# Нужно ли прописывать путь main.sass в index.html

Tags: sass

Нужно ли прописывать путь main.sass в index.html, или достаточно main.css?

Comment: Нет конечно. `sass` надо компилировать в `css` и отдать на чтение `html-лу`

Answer (score 2):

Sass прописывать нигде не нужно, он вообще на сервере не нужен. Это исходник, с которым вы работаете локально, а на сервере используется только результат его компиляции, то есть css.

Comment: я указал путь main.css в index.html, прописываю что либо в main.sass, реакция отсутствует, в чем может быть загвоздка..

Comment: @Rufat Ahmad После того, как вы измените sass, его нужно обработать компилятором scss, который создаст соответствующий css. После этого загружаете css на сервер. Еще есть эффект, что браузер может не сразу подхватить новый css, а использовать старый из своего кеша. Чтобы обновить в хроме, при открытых DevTools тыкаете на кнопку обновления и выбираете "Empty cache and hard reload".

Comment: А как компилируешь `sass`?

Comment: @Air - Запускаю батник в котором две строки: `cd www` и `sass --watch sass:css --sourcemap=inline --style compressed --cache-location sass\.cache`. Scss постоянно висит, и как только какой-нибудь файл в подкаталоге sass изменяется, он его перекомпилирует и записывает скомпилированный css в подкаталог css.